# Why doesn't the FullText search find it?

Tags: php, mysql, search, wampserver, full-text-search

I need a search engine which works on MySql database,
And I have FULLTEXT index on the columns, but for some reason - Sometimes he finds what I ask him for and sometimes he doesn't - And I really don't understand why.

For instance, I have in my MyIsam `songs` table a `name` column which indexed FULLTEXT.

And I have these records:

Sweet child o' mine , Don't Cry

And when I do this query:

```
$query = $msi->query("SELECT `name` FROM songs WHERE MATCH(`name`) AGAINST ('Mine') ");
while($fetch = $query->fetch_assoc())
echo $fetch['name']."<br />";
```

It finds it.

But when I do this:

```
$query = $msi->query("SELECT `name` FROM songs WHERE MATCH(`name`) AGAINST ('Dont') "); // or 'don\'t' , 'dont cry' , 'Don\'t Cry' , etc..
while($fetch = $query->fetch_assoc())
echo $fetch['name']."<br />";
```

It doesn't.

And I really don't understand why..
Another example is that I have another `artist` column on the same table which has a record - 'Sia'.
And even when I do the query to find 'Sia' , it doesn't work!! 
Can someone explain me why?? (it's not the because of the min length - I use in_boolean_mode)

By the way, I use wampserver, so I thought that it might have something to do with that their MySql is not updated to the last version of it or something like that..

Please Help! I'm desperate.. :(

Answer (score 0):

`Dont` is a stop word

You should edit the stop word lists

Comment: "You should edit the stop word lists" - Where can I do that?? :D